# Xamarin.Auth Facebook login doesn't work, vague error message

Tags: android, facebook, xamarin.auth

How to deal with so opaque facebook error? What are some steps to debug this?

I'm trying to attach Facebook Oauth2 authorization to myapp using Xamarin.Auth, but I keep getting the following error:

[image]

I added Android Platform in Facebook Dashboard, Google package name, class name, key hash (followed all steps in Facebook quickstart guide etc) still the same error, i'm so desperate, what can be wrong?

my manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto" package="com.example">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <application android:label="@string/app_label">
        <activity android:name="com.example.Myapp" android:label="@string/app_label" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <string name="facebook_app_id">...</string>
  <string name="app_label">Myapp</string>
</resources>
```

key hash (also tried to generate it from within the app with PackageInfo etc -> same key):

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "%LocalAppData%\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore" | C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl base64
```

Facebook settings:
google play package name: `com.example`
class name: `com.example.Myapp`  (tried com.example.MainActivity here and in manifest.xml - no success too)

MainActivity.cs snippet:

```
namespace Myapp.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "Myapp", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
```

My LoginPageRenderer.cs snippet:

```
var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
                clientId: "...",  // it is valid! I checked
                clientSecret: "...",
                accessTokenUrl: new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token"),
                scope: "email",  // the scopes for the particular API you're accessing, delimited by "+" symbols
                authorizeUrl: new Uri("https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/"),  // the auth URL for the service
                redirectUrl: new Uri("http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"));  // the redirect URL for the service
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in incorrect Valid OAuth redirect URIs (set at Facebook Login page, linked in Facebook Dashboard's side menu)

And there are other settings on that page which obviously are also able to pop up the aforementioned misleading error message.